# Is there a way to use the plotly hovermode "compare" with horizontal lines?

Tags: plotly

I'm trying to generate graphs with mutliple lines, and would like to be able to compare values (and calculate the delta between the lines) in either the vertical axis (comparing y values for a given X value) or horizontal (comparing x values for a given y), and toggle between both modes.

I've found a GH issue at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2155 that shows that the first mode of comparison is possible. But is the horizontal mode possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set `layout.hovermode` to `y` instead of the default `x`.